# Mongoose: alternating schemas inside a schema

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

Using mongoose, I'm trying to define schemas:

```
var BookSchema = new Schema({
  author: String
});

var CarSchema = new Schema({
  color: String
});

var ProductSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  type: String
});
```

I would like to include inside `product` either `car` schema or the `book` schema, based on the value of the `type` field. So that the end results will look as following:

```
[{
  title: 'Think and grow rich',
  type: 'book',
  book: {author: 'Napoleon Hill'}
}, {
  title: 'Toyota corolla',
  type: 'car',
  car: {color: 'red'}
}]
```

So far I found two options, both are not optimal:

1. Include both `car` and `book` in every `product`.
2. Using `Mixed` schema type inside `product`.

Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using discriminators:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html